# Facebook Style Push Notification System

Tags: websocket, notifications, signalr, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

Actually - just a follow up question of

[Building a Notification System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735578/building-a-notification-system)

I just wondering what is the best approach to persist or to store the notification items?

Im choosing between SQL Azure or Table Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs.

If you need high scalablity and/or do not need relational data features, then table storage sounds like a better option.

But again, it depends pretty much in your technical requirements.